# Spyder :An error ocurred while starting the kernel

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, spyder

I am still getting this error: An error occurred while starting the kernel

Things I tried:

1. setuptools command
2. updating spyder
3. Uninstalled everything that had word python in it from Uninstall or change progam panel
4. Uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda
5. Reading people's response on how they tried to fix it
6. Tried not to get frustrated.

This started occurring after I updated the spyder which I shouldn't have, but now I am stuck with the issue. I will share the complete message that's coming up on my IPhython Console screen.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\afsan\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 245, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\afsan\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 213, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in 
import jupyter_client
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 22, in 
import zmq
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 34, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 26, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\afsan\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 245, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\afsan\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 213, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in 
import jupyter_client
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 22, in 
import zmq
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 34, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 26, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\afsan\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 245, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\afsan\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 213, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in 
import jupyter_client
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 22, in 
import zmq
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 34, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 26, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\afsan\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 245, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\afsan\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 213, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in 
import jupyter_client
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 22, in 
import zmq
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 34, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 26, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\afsan\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 245, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\afsan\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 213, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in 
import jupyter_client
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 22, in 
import zmq
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 34, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 26, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have two Python versions installed:

1. `C:\Users\afsan\Anaconda3\`
2. `C:\Users\afsan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36`

Given that it seems you want to use Spyder with Anaconda, please remove your second Python version (manually, if necessary). That should fix your problem.

Comment: Hah! I was wishing you would somehow reply to this. Anyways, I figured what went wrong. Thanks for the light. I now realize that when you do a pip install it installs things into your original python library whereas the conda install, installs things into conda directory. Plus, I updated the spyder through pip whose path I had given in spyder I assume (I don't remember but I can somehow recollect), however, the python version was still the old one. So therefore those two versions gave me a hard time. Really appreciate your quick response. :)